# Transform callbacks into a stream

Tags: perl, inversion-of-control

In Perl, how can one transform a function that requires callbacks to a new function that returns a stream of results?

Image I have a fixed function I can't change:

```
sub my_fixed_handler {
    my $callback = shift;

    my $count = 1;
    while(1) {
       $callback->($count++);
    }
}
```

To print all the a count of numbers I could easily write this code:

```
my_fixed_handler( sub {
    my $num = shift;
    print "...$num\n";
});
```

But now I need another function based on on the `my_fixed_handler` that will return only the result of one calculation step:

```
my $stream = my_wrapper( my_fixer_hander( ... ) ) ;
$stream->next;  # 1
$stream->next;  # 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have access to `$callback`?

Comment: @simbabque  They (we?) write the anonymous sub that's `shift`ed into `$callback` ... ?

Comment: There is https://metacpan.org/pod/Return::MultiLevel which might be helpful, but as long as `$count` is lexical inside of `my_fixed_handler` it's not going to help a lot. Every time you call `my_fixed_handler` it's going to start over, so wrapping it in something that returns all the way out is gonna give you `1` every time.  How is the `$callback` supposed to break the `while (1)` loop?

Comment: Your `my_fixed_handler` would have to be able to keep the state so that it can be used as an iterator.  If it's really "fixed" and you have no access to it then the callback can take that over, but then what's the job of the `handler`?  You can do that, take the logic from `handler` and put it into the callback you send to it.  Then the handler merely provides `1` each time.

Comment: On the other hand, the infinite loop in the handler can't be for real ... perhaps the real code allows other approaches?

Comment: This could be done with threads (or fork).

Comment: @melpomene  By `SIGSTOP`-ing and `SIGCONT`-ing a forked process with the calculation, on each step?

Comment: @zdim No, just let it block while writing to a pipe.

Comment: @melpomene Oh. While the parent is processing what it read the child is blocked on the pipe (in the callback). No need to `STOP` it.  Nice :)

Comment: It is just an example of some code I often see in my projects. I only can control the callback function but not the handler.

Comment: @melpomene  I wrote up that, as it seemed clear that you wouldn't.  If you'd actually would please just post and I'll remove this if it's similar enough. (If I didn't miss something big in it I'll make the reference to your idea more explicit.)

Comment: @zdim You may also want to have a look at threads (or [`forks`](https://metacpan.org/pod/forks), which implements the `threads` API on top of `fork`). :-)

Comment: @melpomene  Right, they can stop and go nicely.  But I just don't reach for them in Perl (while I did use them some and played some more).  In C and C++ there is such a natural choice of when to use `fork` or threads, I'm sorry we don't qiute have that Perl.  While we do have really nice queueing in Perl :). I know of `forks` just haven't got to start using it.  Perhaps this question is a chance :).  I don't know how solid it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the pipe blocks when full: Run the `fixed_handler` in a forked process, with the callback writing back to the parent via a pipe. While the parent is processing after a read the pipe is blocked if full and the writer is waiting. To facilitate this write an extra empty string to fill the pipe.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub fixed_handler {
    my $callback = shift;
    #state $count = 1; # would solve the problem
    my $count = 1;
    for (1..4) { $callback->($count++) }   
}

pipe my $reader, my $writer  or die "Can't open pipe: $!";
$writer->autoflush(1);
$reader->autoflush(1);

my $fill_buff = ' ' x 100_000;  # (64_656 - 3); # see text

my $iter = sub { 
    my $data = shift; 
    say "\twrite on pipe ... ($data)";
    say $writer $data;
    say $writer $fill_buff;     # (over)fill the buffer
};

my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";  #/

if ($pid == 0) {
    close $reader;
    fixed_handler($iter);
    close $writer;
    exit;
}

close $writer;
say "Parent: started kid $pid";

while (my $recd = <$reader>) {
    next if $recd !~ /\S/;      # throw out the filler
    chomp $recd;
    say "got: $recd";
    sleep 1;
}

my $gone = waitpid $pid, 0;
if    ($gone > 0) { say "Child $gone exited with: $?" }
elsif ($gone < 0) { say "No such process: $gone" }
```

Output

```
Parent: started kid 13555
        write on pipe ... (1)
got: 1
        write on pipe ... (2)
got: 2
        write on pipe ... (3)
got: 3
        write on pipe ... (4)
got: 4
Child 13555 exited with: 0
```

At first the writer would keep printing until it fills the buffer.<sup>†</sup> Then, as the reader gets one line, the writer puts another (or two, if prints' length vary), etc. If this is OK, remove `say $writer $fill_buff;`. Then in the output we see all `write on pipe` lines first, then parent's prints go. A common buffer size nowadays is 64K.

However, we are told that each step of `file_handler` takes time and so we'd wait for thousands of such steps before starting the processing in the parent (depending on the size of each write), until the buffer fills and the writer starts getting blocked at each read.

One way out of this is to write an extra string, long enough to fill the buffer, and dismiss it in the reader. I found it finicky to get the exact length for this though.  For one, the buffer found in the program by

```
my $cnt; while (1) { ++$cnt; print $writer ' '; print "\r$cnt" } # reader sleeps
```

differs from the one found on the command line in a similar way. Even with this I still (sometimes) get "double writes." While *that* may not be a show stopper, I went with `100K` to make sure to fill it.

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11946/226064) for discussion of buffer sizes, for example.

Another way may be to set the pipe's buffer size using `IO::Handle::setvbuf`. However, I ran into "*Not implemented on this architecture*" (on production machines) and so I wouldn't consider that.

Messing with buffering will of course slow down the communication a lot.

This implements the idea from [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene)'s comments.

---

<sup>†</sup> With "buffer" I refer to the pipe's buffer (the amount of data written before the pipe blocks, if no data is read on the other side). That are other buffers that get involved but are not as relevant here.

Comment: I can't add votes yet (not enough privileges yet) but thanks for this great answer!

Comment: @Hochstenbach Thanks, glad you like it :).  Let me know if there are questions.